# How to mock patch every method of a class

Tags: python, nose

I have a Test class with as many as 50 different method. I want to patch every method with a mock function.

```
prod = {"foo": "bar"}

def TestClass:
  @patch(db.get_product, return_value=prod)
  def test_1:
    pass
  @patch(db.get_product, return_value=prod)
  def test_2:
    pass
  .
  .
  .
  @patch(db.get_product, return_value=prod)
  def test_50:
    pass
```

Is there any easy way to do this instead of repeating `@patch(db.get_product, return=prod)` 50 times?

Comment: Have you looked at the Mock class? https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/unittest.mock.html#the-mock-class

Answer (score 8):

You can use `patch` as a class decorator instead:

```
@patch(db.get_product, return_value=prod)
class TestClass:
  def test_1:
    pass
  def test_2:
    pass
  .
  .
  .
  def test_50:
    pass
```

Excerpt from the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.patch):

> Patch can be used as a TestCase class decorator. It works by
>   decorating each test method in the class. This reduces the boilerplate
>   code when your test methods share a common patchings set.